# How to reference labels within lstlisting?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

My code is as follows, and I want to reference a Tikz image within the lstlisting environment instead of it being displayed as is. This kind of situation often arises in code comments.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
 
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];  
\node at (0,0) { Center};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{tikzfigure}
\label{circ:center}
\end{figure}
This text refers to the label in the previous Figure \ref{circ:center}.
  \begin{lstlisting}  
//This text refers to the label in the previous Figure \ref{circ:center}.
public class HelloWorld {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");  
    }  
}  
\end{lstlisting}  
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the reference:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
    \node at (0,0) { Center};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{tikzfigure}
  \label{circ:center}
\end{figure}

This text refers to the label in the previous Figure \ref{circ:center}.

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=`']
  //This text refers to the label in the previous Figure `\ref{circ:center}'.
  public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]